# Android onActivityResult not working in first activity

Tags: android

I'm trying to make a Button and when i click on it Moves to another activity , fill 2 fields "name" and "family" click save and go back and show  TextView "fullname"

firstActivity :

```
public class ToDo extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final int Request_Code=1001;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_to_do);

    Button AddNote=findViewById(R.id.todo_btnAddNote);
    AddNote.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(ToDo.this, Todo_saveActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            startActivityForResult(intent,Request_Code);
        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


    if (requestCode==Request_Code &&
            resultCode==RESULT_OK &&
            data !=null){
        String fullname=data.getStringExtra(Todo_saveActivity.result_note);
        Toast.makeText(ToDo.this,fullname,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}

}
```

Second Avtivity:

```
public class Todo_saveActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


public static final String result_note="result";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_todo_save);


    final EditText fullname=findViewById(R.id.todo_name);
   final EditText savefamily=findViewById(R.id.todo_family);



    Button savenote=findViewById(R.id.btn_savenote);
    savenote.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent=new Intent();
            intent.putExtra(result_note,fullname+savefamily.getText().toString());
            setResult(RESULT_OK);
            finish();
        }
    });
}
```

}

when i click on "AddNote" opens 2 activity(IDK why) , after filling both goes back to firstActivity and Toast not showing....

I'm beginner have no idea what should i do , please write me a code after filling fields show it as a textview on firstActivity
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your click listener you need to remove this line `startActivity(intent);`

When you want to use onActivityResult you call `startActivityForResult(intent,Request_Code);` like you have, but since you have `startActivity(intent);` before that I think it is starting the second activity without knowing to expect that you want to use onActivityResult.

Comment: Thanks...now 1 activity opens.but still no Toast

Comment: Sorry, you also need to pass the data back.  So change setResult(RESULT_OK); to setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);

Comment: @codeMagic is right, you should set a log/breakpoint to see if all of the conditions are met for the "if-statement" that surrounds your toast.

Comment: Thanks. now Toast popup (but its not only the name...its widget appcompat ...) and what should i do to turn it a TextView in firstactivity?

Comment: Yeah, it looks like you're passing the widget "fullname" back in the intent instead of getting the string from it, so change 

intent.putExtra(result_note, fullname.getText().toString() + savefamily.getText().toString());

Comment: To turn it into a TextView in the first activity you need to create that textview in the first activity's layout, and then you can set the text on it by calling textview.setText(fullname);

Comment: U are Amazing man...sorry can u say exactly where to setText on fullname...i created the fullname TextView but dont know where to add

Comment: So you created the textView, then inside of onActivityResult you can call setText on the textView that you created.  You'll have to create the textView variable outside of onCreate, so up above onCreate you'll have to create the textview variable, then inside of onCreate is where you'll do textview = findViewById(R.id.whatever_your_id_is),  then inside of onActivityResult below your "fullname" variable you can call textview.setText(fullname)

Comment: Sorry i'm beginner
 I added this above oncreate public TextView Textview;(idk what variable is xD)
and this in oncreate :     
 TextView textView=findViewById(R.id.Fullname);

and this below String fullname:
            textView.setText(fullname);

And unfortunately stopped :)

Comment: No worries! You’re almost there. So the part inside onCreate should just be textView=findViewById(R.id.Fullname);  So leave off “TextView”.  Also, inside AndroidStudio if you look at the bottom there should be a button that says “logcat”. You can click on that and it’ll show you the error why the app crashed

Comment: THANKS Finaly Worked!
soo....is there an easy way to make new names add above last name? :))
 i know recyclerview and data model a bit...

Comment: No problem! Welcome to the world of Android :) Yeah, your best bet will be to make a list of Strings that you can store the names in, then add each new name that gets created to that list. Then to display the list you can use a recyclerview. There are lots of good tutorials for recyclerviews out there to get you started!